# Skipping blank fields for address labels using datatool and envlab

Tags: errors, datatool, envlab

I am trying to process the following into Avery 5160 mailing labels, using the `\skipblank` code that someone else posted on this site to suppress blank lines:

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{letter}  
\usepackage[avery5160label,noprintbarcodes]{envlab}  
\usepackage{datatool}  
\usepackage{makerobust}  
\makeatletter  
%commands to skip blank or missing fields  
%* version replaces with space only  
    \newcommand\skipblank{\@ifstar\@spskip\@nlskip}  
    \newcommand\@nlskip[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{\relax}{#1\\}}  
    \newcommand\@spskip[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{\relax}{#1\space}}  
\MakeRobustCommand{\@nlskip}  
\MakeRobustCommand{\@spskip}  
\makeatother  

\makelabels
\begin{document}
\startlabels

\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloadrawdb{maillist}{sitemailmerge.csv}


\DTLforeach{maillist}    {\name=Contact,\site=SiteName,\addra=Addressa,\addrb=Addressb,\addrc=Addressc,\city=City,\st=StateProv,\zip=PostCode,\country=Country,\role=Role,\fname=Firstname,\lname=Lastname,\tit=Title}{%  


\mlabel{  
\skipblank*{\name},\ \skipblank*{\role}\\  
\skipblank{\site}  
\skipblank{\addra}  
\skipblank{\addrb}  
\skipblank{\addrc}  
\city\ \st\ \zip\ \ \country  

    }  
}  

\end{document}
```

---

But I keep getting the following LaTeX error:

```
"
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
                \inaccessible
l.43 }

?
! Missing { inserted.
<recently read> }

l.43 }

?
! Missing } inserted.
"
```

It was my understanding that unmatched `}` errors were related to fragile commands, hence the use of `\MakeRobustCommand{}`, but this doesn't seem to help. It is extremely frustrating.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide some entries of you csv file. Up to now we can't test your example.

Comment: Without a complete demo, we can't hope to answer this.